# PreExecute() function in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I developed an application using symfony2, I want to know how to write preExecute() function symfony2 for following case: 
when I log-in into the system; it redirect me on user profile section when I log-out from same screen, It killed session and redirect me on login screen, but when I hit browser's back button then it will redirect me on profile screen, which shows me all user information but when I click for next process from same screen then I redirect me on login page.

I just want to add preExecute function like symfony1.4 for this case, so I checked session and if it is null then it will redirect me on login page if I hit browser's back button when I alrady log-out from the system.

I already added following code in profileController.php files,

```
public function indexAction() {
    $session = $this->get('request')->getSession();
    $userId = $session->get('id');

    if ($userId == 0 || $userId == '') {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_security_login'));
    } else {
        //my code 
    }
}

//logout action
public function dologoutAction(){
   $this->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
   $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
   $this->container->get('request')->getSession('session')->clear();
   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_security_login'));
}
```

if there is any other way to handle this case then please help me for the same.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just require the `ROLE_USER` role on the profile action and the firewall will do the redirect-to-the-login-form-and-then-redirect-back stuff:

```php
/**
 * @Secure("ROLE_USER")
 */
public function profileAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

For more information read the [*Security* chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) of the Symfony book.